# Lenovo u400, Ubuntu 12.04. Sudden reboots / power down

Tags: 12.04, lenovo, ideapad

I've recently bought a Lenovo u400 (http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/laptop/ideapad/u-series/u400/) and installed Ubuntu 12.04 on it.

Everything works fine (I've installed the proprietary ATI drivers for switchable graphics) except that I get a random power down or reboot either while surfing the web or watching videos.

Monitoring the temperature with sensors, the laptop never goes into any critical zone but still may power down or reboot once in a while. Is there any logs that I should check and any particular message I should take note of?

EDIT: This happens to me as well. This also happens without proprietary drivers activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with the U400. I didn't found any hints to solve this so I completely reinstalled Ubuntu. That seems to fixed it.

I am interested if the Intel virtualization could be the reason. Do you have enabled it in the BIOS settings? At my first installation it was enabled. Now I've done a reinstallation with the Intel virtualization disabled and it runs without any reboots. Maybe it's just a hazard.

Comment: I can't remember if Intel VT is enabled but I've reinstalled Ubuntu thrice with the same issues so you might be right. Don't have access to the U400 until the weekends so I'll mark your answer right and see if others with the same issue can comment.

Thanks!